# WiFi and Ethernet not working after update my system on Ubuntu 22.10. Kernel driver : bcma-pci-bridge

Tags: networking, wireless, kernel, ethernet, 22.10

I install new update, after that my wifi and Ethernet don’t work. The card is present, but it is not recognized by the system. Here is my output when type : lspci-nnk | grep 0280 and dmesg| grep bcma

```
root@mdtalloc19:-# lspci -nk | grep 0280 -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiartes BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [144:43591
DeviceName: WLAN
subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiartes BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [144:052]
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

---

Here is my output when  i type ‘ifconfig’ :
‘ mdtalloc19andialloc19: $ ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099 UP, BROADCAST, MULTICAST> mtu 1500
net 172.17.0.1 netmask 255.255.0.0 broadcast 172.17.255.255
ether 02:42:d4:fe:11:71 txqueuelen 0 (Ethernet)
RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
RX errors 0 dropped 0. overruns o frame o
TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
TX errors o dropped 0 overruns o carrier o collisions

Lo:flags=73<UP, LOOPBACK , RUNNING> mtu 65536
inet 127.0.0.1
netmask 255.0.0.0
inet6 : :1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10 loop txqueuelen 1000
• (Boucle locale)
RX packets 3711 bytes 269260 (269.2 KB)
RX errors o dropped o overruns 0 frame o
TX packets 3711 bytes 269260 (269.2 KB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0´

And for lspci -v | grep -i network -A 8

´ mdialloc19@ndialloc19: $ 1spci -v Igrep -i network -A 8

03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43228 802.113/b/9/n
DeviceName: WLAN
Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
Physical Slot: 0-2
Flags: bus master, fast devsel,
, Latency o,
• IRO 19
Memory at d3000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size-16k]
Capabilities: 
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
Kernel modules: bcma ´

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Boot with a previous kernel and check if `fimware-b43-installer` is installed.

Comment: Just to understand, why you say that the wireless card is not recognized?
Please post the output of `ifconfig` edited: please post also the output of `lspci -v | grep -i network -A 8`

Comment: Please edit your question to show the results of: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` and also: `sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source| grep Status` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.